# Editing symbology of contour lines with ArcPy

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-desktop, labeling, contour

I just have a problem with my Python script.  I had run the Contour-tool to generate polylines.

```
Contour("rectExtract", "C:/fakepath/Class10.shp", 20,0)
```

Now I want to mark the 100 meter lines in another colour.

Comment: You could create a .lyr file with the 100' symbology then apply it programmatically with python.

Comment: @Roy i will use the symbology of an .lyr file thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Roy suggested, doing this using a layer file (which you can add to your map using arcpy.mapping.AddLayer) is the way to go.

To author that layer file just classify the symbology of your layer as being 100' in one colour and everything else in another.  Then save that layer as a layer file.